# Обмен данными между вкладками одного сайта

Tags: javascript, html5

Понадобились такие возможности:

- узнать список открытых вкладок (в пределах одного домена, разумеется);
- обмениваться данными между этими вкладками

Есть ли в современном хтмл5 подобное апи? (кроме cookie и localStorage)

Comment: А зачем, собственно, вам это нужно?  
Может, есть способ проще?

Comment: Надо. Очень-очень сильно надо. Поверьте на слово.

Comment: А в чём собственно проблема? Каждая вкладка при старте посылает на сервер handshake вначале и затем ping каждые, скажем, 10 секунд. И подписывается на сообщения (websocket, допустим, или обыкновенный long polling). Когда на сервер приходит handshake от новой вкладки, он выделяет ей id и отсылает назад. Если долго не приходит ping, вкладка считается зависшей или закрытой. При приходе новой вкладки всем рассылается сообщение об этом. То же если вкладка посылает broadcast.

Неужели такая простая штука ещё никем не реализована? Если нет, вы будете первым.

Comment: А можно задачу описать?

Чисто любопытство.

Comment: @VladD (и deterok тоже): как раз для веб-сокетов нужно. То что вы предлагаете - это одно соединение на каждую вкладку. Я хочу сделать согласованность вкладок, чтобы было одно соединение, независимо от количества открытых вкладок. И данные будут раздаваться с главной вкладки (на которой открыт вебсокет) на все остальные.

Comment: Понимаю, можно и посредством localstorage добиться, но это слишком костыльный метод, возможно современное хтмл5 апи поддерживает что-то по назначению?

Comment: @kanaris: Не думаю, что браузер позволит просто так пересылать данные между вкладками без участия сервера. Но я не специалист, послушаем, что скажут спецы.

Answer (score 7):

1. [SharedWorker](http://caniuse.com/#search=SharedWorker) — очень слабая поддержка
2. [LocalConnection](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html) — Flash и все вытекающие из этого проблемы
3. [BNC Connector](http://theprivateland.com/bncconnector/home.htm) — убер-штука, эмуляция TPC/IP через cookie, все браузеры
4. [wormhole.js](http://rubaxa.github.io/wormhole/) — SharedWorker + LocalStorage, есть возможность узнать кол-во открытых вкладок, поддерживает Master/Slave, а так же CORS (но пока сыро и временно заморожено, есть более важные задачи)

Comment: Вроде Google что-то на эту тему недавно предлагал, вроде на хабре читал в еженедельном дайджесте посвещенному вебу.

Comment: @kanaris Как я понимаю, вы пытаетесь решить ровно то, что пытались мы, это держать одно соединение на все вкладки, вот простой пример решения этой задачи:

    wormhole().on('master', function () {
      // Если вкладка стала master создаем соединение с сервером
      createTransport(function (transport) {
        // Подписываемся на события от сервера
        transport.on('message', function (data) {
          // Рассылаем данные между табами
          wormhole().emit('message', data);
        });
      });
    });
    
    wormhole().on('message', function (data) {
      // ...
    });

Comment: если платформа не универсальная, то однозначно sharedworker. остальное будет глючить. в частности после закрытия "главной" вкладки у вас будут выборы нового главного и переустановка соединения. при восстановлении открытых вкладок тоже выборы, причем надо как-то задетектить что это восстановление, с этим есть сложности, например хром восстанавливает сессинные куки...

Comment: @eicto SharedWorker глючит ещё в как, именно поэтому мы его пока выключили, с того не сего мастер просто «исчезает», LocalStorage работает достаточно стабильно, выбор master происходит практически мгновенно (30-70ms), в это время все события и команды копятся на каждом slave и после выбора master синхронизируются. Основная проблема во всяких Safari и IE < 9, а так механизм достаточно стабильный. Не очень понял про «задетектить, что это восстановление» зачем?

Comment: ну как у вас работает система когда сразу несколько вкладок вашего приложения открыты при старте браузера ? Пропадание мастера не критично, если он создается сразу, в моей задаче было важно, чтобы не было сразу два мастера.

Comment: Кто первый, то и прав, LocalStorage синхронный же, а реализация достаточно стандартная, обычная проверка раз в N-sec жив ли ещё мастер (можете посмотреть в исходниках, там ничего сложно), ну и, конечно, тесты, тесты и ещё раз тесты, постарался покрыть все возможные случаи, даже ваш случая [можно воспроизвести][1], пока ;] 

[1]: http://jsbin.com/juwita/1/edit?js,console

Comment: только что проверил, wormhole сильно глючит при восстановлении сессии, даже в демке на сайте, показывает на одну больше вкладку, при переключении вызывает выборы, что ли, потому что при открытых 5-ти вкладках показывал сначала 6, потом через секунду 3, а потом 5. Полагаться на него как-то странно было бы, если вам нужен только один мастер. (браузер гуглохром 42.0.2292.0 в стабильной тоже самое должно быть версии, т.к. такая система в принципе не может надежно работать)

Comment: это уже должно работать на демке? Я только что перепроверил - всё то же самое, я вообще-то уверен, что такой подход не может работать нормально в хроме. Я так понимаю, с черненьким кружочком - мастер? Я только что видел в течение более чем 5 секунд четыре мастера сразу, из 6 вкладок.

Comment: Печаль... увы, [воспроизвести пока не могу][1], но верю, больше одной точки это не хорошо. Значит нужно копать глубже, SharedWorker пока тоже сырой (сейчас включил его, вроде работает, ну нужно, чтобы он день висел, чтобы точно ответить), ну и поддержка слабая. Насчет возможно не возможно, тут не соглашусь, загвоздка именно в восстановлении сессии, хотя теоретически и при закрытии мастера может быть такая ситуация, надо думать над workaround, короче, одним часом тут не отделаешься.

[1]: http://recordit.co/rfrliEQLxq

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, это то, что Вам нужно http://ldalab.ru/post/obmen_soobweniyami_mezhdu_documentami.html

Comment: да, интерфейс тот, но как сделать обмен между вкладками, а не фреймами, созданными на веб-странице?

Comment: Цитата из статьи: "Это средство обеспечивает безопасный обмен сообщениями через границы фреймов, вкладок и окон.".
Почитайте про Cross Document Messaging.

Comment: Видел это предложение, но про вкладки ничего не нашел. Продолжаю поиски.

Comment: Для отправки сообщения в другую вкладку вам нужно получить объект window этого окна/вкладки/фрэйма. Вызвать функцию postMessage этого объекта. У объекта window должен быть зарегистрирован соответствующий обработчик.
http://www.w3.org/TR/webmessaging/#web-messaging

Comment: @main, получить объект для передачи сообщений в него нельзя, только через родственные объекты - дочернее/родительское окно.

Comment: @TheDoctor, А пруф можно? В стандарте ничего про это не нашел.

Comment: @main механизма передачи объектов подобного типа просто нет. в смысле сообщением нельзя передать объект типа window, а сообщения позволяют только transferable объекты передавать. (вот например через localstorage можно передать копию blob используя URL.createObjectURL) но window вы так не передадите.

Comment: Речь не идет об отправке объекта window. Речь идет о вызове метода postMessage() объекта window для отправки в него сообщений, как это описано в примере по ссылке http://www.w3.org/TR/webmessaging/#web-messaging.

Comment: так а как вы получите объект window чтобы вызвать **его** метод postMessage ? :)